# Flex app for quizzing

Tags: php, mysqli, quiz

This is from a flex app that is for quizzing. It calls the database for the question and then checks to see if it has been tagged (bookmarked) by a user already. "Question" is a value object and "Tag" is also a value object.

I just wanted to post it to see how it could be better. It works fine, but I feel that since I am new to this, it probably isn't best.

```
public function getQuestionByNumber($itemNum, $userID) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
          "SELECT
                        questions.id, questions.question_number, questions.chapter_id, questions.section_id, 
                        questions.question_txt, questions.answers, questions.feedbacks, questions.correct_answer, 
                        questions.question_type, questions.module, questions.shuffle_answer,
                        questions.tags
           FROM questions where questions.question_number=?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemNum); $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      $row = new Question();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->id, $row->question_number, $row->chapter_id, $row->section_id, 
                                        $row->question_txt, $row->answers, $row->feedbacks, $row->correct_answer, 
                                        $row->question_type, $row->module, $row->shuffle_answer, $row->tags);


          if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

              } else {
                          return null;
                  }
            mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
          "SELECT
                        id
           FROM tagged where user_id =? && question_number=?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ii', $userID, $itemNum);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();

      $tag = new Tag();

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $tag->id);

      if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2)) {
                  $row->tagged = $tag->id;
                  return $row;
      } else {
                  $row->tagged = 0;
                  return $row;
          }


      mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt2);
      mysqli_close($this->connection);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine your two SQL queries so you don't have to hit the database twice.

The new SQL statement would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    q.id, q.question_number, q.chapter_id, q.section_id, 
    q.question_txt, q.answers, q.feedbacks, q.correct_answer, 
    q.question_type, q.module, q.shuffle_answer,
    q.tags, COALESCE(t.id, 0) As tagged
FROM questions q
     LEFT JOIN tagged t ON q.question_number = t.question_number AND t.user_id = ?
WHERE q.question_number=?
```

The COALESCE function would return the id from the tagged table if one exists, otherwise it returns 0.  This eliminates the need for your final if/else statement and gives you a direct mapping for $row->tagged.

You should also release all result sets and close all connections **before** issuing a return statement.  Any code after a return statement will not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into the COALESCE function and learn more about it. Also I didn't know that code after a return statement would not be executed. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: The re-write worked great! I learned a lot. On your second point about closing connections, I stuck the free result and close statements in the if() statement before the return. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: It's better, but it still wouldn't close the connection in the case where your query didn't return anything.  What I'd do is rewrite the `if/else` altogether.  Make the condition `if (!mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) { $row = null }`.  This would only happen if you got no results from the SQL.  After that, free the result, close the connection, then `return $row`.